# I encrypt HDD during installing Ubuntu , install fails and now I can't install Ubuntu again

Tags: hard-drive, decryption

I press to encrypt Ubuntu hdd during install , somehow install failed . No every time I try to install again installation failed possible because of encryption of the HDD. I tried to decrypt with usb medium with try Ubuntu with no result.

Comment: There are not enough details here to answer. I suggest you start over and follow the [official tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop). It would also be wise to [verify your download](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu). If you still need help, please reference the tutorial when asking so we know exactly where you're stuck. Give exact/reproducible details. Use the exact terms and exact actions as they happen on your system. Avoid summarizing in your own words because we won't be able to pinpoint the exact nature of your problem.